# How to add shadow only for the border?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add shadow around collectionview cells. But the shadow is around the images and labels in the cell, and no shadow around the cell. Does someone know how to work it out?

```
    cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
    cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    cell.layer.masksToBounds = false
    cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
    cell.layer.shadowRadius = 1
```

[Shadow around the content(not the border)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gagZD.png)

Comment: I don't understand what you want? You want the cell to have a shadow but not the contents of the cell?

Comment: @Brandon Just now add a picture in the post, that's the shadow with the content, but not the border

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying shadow to `contentView` directly hence it is not working. You need to take a view inside your contentView, put all your content in this view and give some padding (e.g. 8pt) from all side.

Suppose I have named this view as `vwContainer`, then:

```
@IBOutlet weak var vwContainer: UIView!
let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: vwContainer.bounds)
vwContainer.layer.masksToBounds = false
vwContainer.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
vwContainer.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 5.0)
vwContainer.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
vwContainer.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath
```

If you are trying to achieve any other UI than please update your question with image.

Answer (score 1):

```
extension UIView {
    func addShadow(color: UIColor, radius: CGFloat = 1, offset: CGSize) {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        self.layer.shadowOffset = offset
        self.layer.shadowRadius = radius
        self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath
    }
}
```

Use it as:

let offset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)

cell.addShadow(color: .black, offset: offset)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set background color for the contentView as below

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .white
```